# Recover ext4 filesystem on LVM with corrupted superblocks

Tags: arch-linux, lvm, ext4, corruption

After a power outage, an EXT4 fs inside an LV had its superblocks corrupted, and can't be mounted. The LVs are all within the same physical disk and VG. The disk doesn't appear to be corrupted, only the filesystems.

I had another outage a few days ago in which the same exact thing happened with another, less important fs (also EXT4). I have many other LVs, most of them EXT4 and all were still mounted before the forceful shutdown. Though only these two became corrupted.

The only patterns I could see so far between both broken filesystems, and between both outages were:

- Both were *almost* the only ones that had their LVs (and filesystems) resized on-line before the shutdowns. Lvresize and resize2fs were done accordingly.
- Both were ext4, there was a third filesystem that was also on-live resized before the last outage, this one wasn't corrupted, but it was the only btrfs one.

My fair guess is that it could have something to do with the forceful shutdown, without an unmount not letting some information about the live resizing be updated? Both filesystems were working perfectly both before and after the resize, with the outage being the detonator.

Some of tests I've made were:

> sudo mount /dev/vg00/dshark /mnt

```
mount: /mnt: cannot mount; probably corrupted filesystem on /dev/mapper/vg00-dshark.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

After a mount attempt, dmesg returns:

`[18041.892096] EXT4-fs (dm-22): VFS: Found ext4 filesystem with invalid superblock checksum.  Run e2fsck?`

> sudo e2fsck /dev/vg00/dshark

```
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/vg00/dshark

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

/dev/vg00/dshark contains a ext4 file system
```

I've also tried checking where the superblocks should be stored in with:

> sudo mke2fs -n /dev/vg00/dshark

```
mke2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
/dev/vg00/dshark_snap contains a ext4 file system
Proceed anyway? (y,N) y
Creating filesystem with 14155776 4k blocks and 3538944 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 0c642ec1-e5e1-41ab-95ff-8f9054058fa6
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208,
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424
```

Trying out e2fsck -b {*superblock*} with any of those values gives the same result as the one above. Well except for one case:

> sudo e2fsck -b 884736 /dev/vg00/dshark_snap

```
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
e2fsck: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/vg00/dshark_snap
Could this be a zero-length partition?
```

Any help in restoring the filesystem, or *at worst* salvaging, is much appreciated! Also finding out what causes it could be very helpful in preventing further corruptions. If more information is necessary I'll update the question. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Comment: If nothing else helps, please give R-Studio a try: https://www.r-studio.com/?GIMCX000